# Configurate SAML Auth on Postman

Tags: symfony, postman, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I'm new in SAML and Shibboleth. I developed my API using Symfony and i have a shibboleth (SAML 2.0) security provider. My application works well. My problem is that i didn't find how can i configurate authentification on a rest client (postman) to use my API.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that SAML and OAuth are different protocols with different token types. SAML is XML with lots of assertions (claims) and OAuth is JSON with essentially a canned set of attributes.

Postman requires a JWT token. It won't work with a SAML token.